# JQuery Widget Factory override _setOptions

Tags: jquery, jquery-widgets

I am trying to override the built in _setOptions method of the jQuery Widget Factory, but I don't know how to call the parent _setOptions function.  I am using jQuery 1.8.24 so I can't use the `super` method which is available in 1.9+ only.

```
      _setOption: function(key, value){
          console.log('key => '+ key + '; value => '+ value); // Test to see if this gets called
          if(this[key] != value) {
              $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply(this,arguments); // Call the parent option
          }    
      },   

      _setOptions: function(options){
          console.log('Config multi options');
          console.log(options);
          //$.Widget.prototype._setOptions.apply(this, options); // throws error
          // Ripped out the guts of Widget _setOptions for now.  Feels hackish.
          var self = this;
          $.each(options, function(key, value) {
              self._setOption(key, value);
          });
          // What to do after finished setting multiple options.
          this._configureVideo();
          this.play();
      },
```

[jquery UI 1.9 WidgetFactory Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_setOptions)

Comment: I believe _methods are private by convention when using jQuery Widgets

Comment: You are technically correct.  However, you can still override those methods and they are still `private` to you and your widget.  Without the `_` they are public methods accessible by the front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this._setOption();